# I would like that the value of an Int variable is equal to the number of items inside an array of different type (Swift)

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3

I would like that the `var numberPlaces` of type `Int` get the same value of filteredList

```
list = NearbyPlaces.getCategories()

filteredList = list.filter { _ in
    arc4random() % 2 == 0
}
```

but `filteredList` is of type `QCategoryy`so how can i do? Because i want that `numberPlaces` Int value is egual to the number of items inside `filteredList`.

UPDATE

`numberPlaces` is in my next viewController

```
var numberPlaces = 0
```

and in the previous controller in my prepare function

```
 if let np = segue.destination as? CourseClass2 {


            np.categories = filteredList
            np.numberPlaces = //here the number of items of filteredList
            np.radius = Int(stepperRadius.value)
        }
```

Comment: Where is var numberPlaces? Please show whole relevant code

Comment: i updated the question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd wager your `filteredList` is **not** of type `QCategoryy`. It might be of type `[QCategoryy]`, an array of `QCategoryy` objects.

You should be able to just:

```
np.numberPlaces = filteredList.count
```